# Cannot load old saves in complete edition

Tags: bloodborne

I had physical copy of the game. The complete edition was on sale on PSN so I bought it and deleted the physical copy from the feed bar and downloaded the digital copy. Now I can’t use my old saves. When I try to load an old save it tells me the game isn’t completely installed

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I've found this [2 year old reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/bloodborne/comments/30eima/ps4_update_250_corrupted_my_save_file_and_how_i/) with similar problem:

> After loading the game and trying to "continue" or "load game", I would get a pop-up message saying "Game install incomplete, could not load game."

And this is how author fixed it:

> Start up Bloodborne and start a "new game". Once you are in control of your character back out to the main menu and you should be able to choose "load game" and load your save file.

I suggest you backing up saves to flash drive before trying this.